# Heroku - Manage different application from terminal

Tags: heroku, command-line, terminal, ubuntu-18.04, heroku-cli

I have a heroku account which is now storing two applications with example names *loon-plotter* and *new-site*. In my command line, I am wanting to run bash inside of *loon-plotter's dyno* (container) but the current terminals currently focused is on the *new-site* application.

What this means is I have to command `$ heroku run bash --app loon-plotter` to run bash inside of loon-plotter. However, I would like to know how I could switch what application the terminal is managing / focused on?

An outcome of this would be I could call `$ heroku run bash` to run bash in loon-plotter (without specification of which application I want!).

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To specify the Heroku app in the terminal, you need to add the app (remote) to the local repository. The command to do this is `heroku git:remote -a app_name`

Source: [Deploying with Git](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git)